# Cannot dual boot Ubuntu/Windows 10 on HP laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, hp

I've been trying to install and run Ubuntu on my HP laptop (HP laptop 15t-dy100, Core i5 U series 10th gen Intel processor, 12GB RAM, 64-bit OS, x64base processor) for the past few days with no avail. I've set aside about 90GB of unallocated disk space for Ubuntu, tried install/boot with Secure Boot on and off, I've let Ubuntu partition for dual boot and I've tried manually (25GB /, 64GB /home, 6GB Linux-swap, EFI folder I just selected the one Windows came with), but nothing seems to work. Most often it returns no errors (except the occasional flash of "error communicating to TPM Chip", but I don't think that would affect boot).

I've been through the EFI files, no sign of Ubuntu or grub2, however, I can boot from a USB drive, which some others with a similar issue couldn't. When setting up the live USB I used Rufus (I tried both MBR and GPT systems just because it wasn't working when installing (live USB worked though), although I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter with UEFI). I tried looking further into it with EasyUEFI, which does list Ubuntu, but the file path doesn't actually exist.

Partitioning:

[image: Partitioning]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

UEFI settings:

[image: settings]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
[image: security]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
[image: Config]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
[image: Boot Options]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Boot Options + error:
[image: Boot Options]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
[image: EFI Boot Options]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
[image: No Valid File Error]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to go into GParted and create two different partitions first: one with swap, and one with ext4.  When doing the setup wizard, I was then able to partition manually, and use the ext4 as /, and swap would automatically sync.  I also used /dev/nvme0n1 as the bootloader device, and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1
If you have dual boot with windows then create partitions using the disk management tool according to what amount of disk space you want to give to Ubuntu. Also create a partition to provide swap to Linux.

Method 2
If you have installation errors or if you accidentally removed windows the use live Ubuntu usb and create partition of your choice. According to me use only the / directory with ext4 filesystem. Ignore /home.

Comment: There were no installation errors and Windows is still intact.  For Method 1, I gave about 90GB for Ubuntu to use, and I provided the recomended space for /, /home, and swap.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't already do this when you installed Ubuntu, it's best to select "/" as the device for bootloader installation.  That way, you'll boot straight into grub2 and then can boot into Windows or Ubuntu (Ubuntu by default).

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and selected the new "/" as the device for bootloader installation, but it didn't work.  When I go into the boot device options in UEFI there is the option for the Windows bootloader and an option for EFI.  I selected EFI. Ubuntu was there, I selected it, and it came up with a no valid file error.  Same as with Ubuntu's automatic partitioning option to dual boot in installation.